# How to stop text from being clickable after anchor tag is off?

Tags: html, anchor

I don't know how to really explain it, but whenever I'm using the anchor tag like the one below, the last element is still underlined and clickable. I'm a beginner, so I'm too sure why this is happening, I've even watched videos to see how to remove that link, but I don't know how to really describe more than this.

````
<body>
<a href = "www.google.com </a>"
 <p class= "Google"> Google </p>
 <p> The website above is google. </p>
</body>
</html>```
![End Result](https://imgur.com/a/DTCo99i)
````

Comment: That <a> tag should follow this format: `<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>`

Comment: Are you trying to _remove_ the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your code.Below is correct version.

```
<body>
<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
 <p> The website above is google. </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<body>
    <a href="www.google.com">
      <p class="google"> Google </p>
    </a>
    <p> The website above is google. </p> 
</body>
```